# Change logging colors in PyDev windows

Tags: python, logging, pydev

I'm using PyDev and I'm trying to change the default colors of the logging messages (for example - make info green...).
I've tried to use colorlog and colorama but the colors in the console (both standard and interactive) remain the same.

Below is the code I've used:

```
import logging
import colorlog
from colorlog import ColoredFormatter
import colorama
from colorama import init
init()

formatter = ColoredFormatter("%(log_color)s%(levelname)-8s%(reset)s %(blue)s%(message)s",
    datefmt=None,
    reset=True,
    log_colors={
        'DEBUG':    'cyan',
        'INFO':     'green',
        'WARNING':  'yellow',
        'ERROR':    'red',
        'CRITICAL': 'red',
    }
)

logger = logging.getLogger('example')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

return logger


def main():
"""Create and use a logger."""
logger = setup_logger()

logger.debug('a debug message')
logger.info('an info message')
logger.warning('a warning message')
logger.error('an error message')
logger.critical('a critical message')


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, by default the Eclipse Console view doesn't handle ANSI escape colors properly, but you can install a plugin to enable it:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ansi-escape-console

By using this plugin it should show colors properly when you do a regular run...

I'm pasting code below which shows how to deal with the ansi escape sequences properly:

```
class AnsiColors:
    FG_BLACK        = '\033[30m'
    FG_RED          = '\033[31m'
    FG_GREEN        = '\033[32m'
    FG_YELLOW       = '\033[33m'
    FG_BLUE         = '\033[34m'
    FG_MAGENTA      = '\033[35m'
    FG_CYAN         = '\033[36m'
    FG_WHITE        = '\033[37m'

    BG_BLACK        = '\033[40m'
    BG_RED          = '\033[41m'
    BG_GREEN        = '\033[42m'
    BG_YELLOW       = '\033[43m'
    BG_BLUE         = '\033[44m'
    BG_MAGENTA      = '\033[45m'
    BG_CYAN         = '\033[46m'
    BG_WHITE        = '\033[47m'

    END             = '\033[0m'

for d in dir(AnsiColors):
    if d.startswith("FG"):
        print(getattr(AnsiColors, d) + d + AnsiColors.END)
    if d.startswith("BG"):
        print(getattr(AnsiColors, d) + d + AnsiColors.END)
```

This should give an output such as:

[image]

Note that it should work in the interactive console by default too, but unfortunately there's a bug in PyDev 4.3.0 which prevents it from working properly (but it'll be fixed for PyDev 4.4.0).

Comment: Oh, as a note, you have to disable the ansi console plugin in the interactive interpreter (because while it makes the output correct in the regular run, it messes things up in the interactive console which should already handle the ansi escape sequences).

Comment: Thank you for the notice about PyDev < 4.3.0 incompatibility! Upgrading PyDev version and installing the aforementionned plugin did the trick for me on windows.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin that worked for me is Grepconsole. You can type patterns to colors in the console. Like "debug" or "warning" or more complicated patterns :)